# How to return first object of a collection from its parent

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am looking to do the following with a single database query if possible.

```
public class Location
{
    public string URL {get;set;}
    public IList<Page> Pages {get;set;}
}

Page firstPage = Session.Linq<Location>()
                .Where(location => location.URL == "some-location-url")
                .Select(location => location.Pages).FirstOrDefault();
```

My aim is based on the current location url, return the first Page object from its pages collection.

I have tried a number of different ways now and they all seem to execute many queries to get the desired Page object out.

Any help is appreciated!

Dave the Ninja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what your looking for:

```
Page firstPage = Session.Linq<Page>()
.OrderBy(page => page.Index)
.FirstOrDefault(page=> page.Location.URL == "some-location-url");
```

I'm making the assumption that the page has a Location property that relates back to the Location it belongs to and the .Index would be the property you want to order with.

Comment: Yes, however the reason for loading from the Locations collection is that the Pages are an ordered List.

I need to be able to return the 1st page from that ordered list.

Comment: I had implemented this before by exposing the Index as a get only (set by Access.AsCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)) 

Not ideal but looks like the only way forward with this one.

Cheers for confirming Chris

Answer (score 0):

Run the query against `Page` instead of against `Location`: you don't need to return the `Location` record at all.

```
(from p in AllPages
where p.Location.URL == "some-location-url"
select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

[Almost always when I get stuck with writing a LINQ query, I find it helps to start building the query from the bottom-most object in the parent-child relationships involved.]

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. As I commented on Chris's answer, the Page collection is an ordered list so I need to be sure im getting the first Page from the order specified within the Locations pages collection

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a order by directly to the mapping of the collection. You could then do

```
Page firstPage = Session.Linq<Location>()
              .Where(location => location.URL == "some-location-url")
              .Select(location => location.Pages.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault();
```

The FirstOrDefault may stop NHibernate making all the selects.

No Guarantee  on this as I haven't got linq to nhibernate set up to test it.

Comment: Yeh, as soon as FirstOrDefault is executed there is a query to the DB.